# Check whether '.' and '/' are escaped properly

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I'm currently using a function to check if a URL has correctly escaped two different characters: `.` and `/`.

To escape a character within a string, it requires 2 preceding `\`'s in the string (i.e.: `\\.` or `\\/`).

Here is the code I'm currently using. As you can see I'm matching the string with some regex, and then for every element returned I check if the first character of the string is `\`.

I feel this could be simplified, how can I make this better and avoid looping through all elements returned by `match`?

```js
function isValidEscapedString(value) {
  return (value.match(/.?[./]/g)||[]).every((escape) => escape[0] === '\\');
}

console.log(isValidEscapedString('')); // true
console.log(isValidEscapedString('https://stackoverflow.com')); // false
console.log(isValidEscapedString('https:\/\/stackoverflow\.com')); // false
console.log(isValidEscapedString('https://stackoverflow\\.com')); // false
console.log(isValidEscapedString('https:\\/\\/stackoverflow\\.com')); //true
```

*The examples in the code are working as intended.*

Comment: Why are you specifically escaping `.`  and `/`? For `RegExp` constructor or something else?

Comment: @adiga yes that's right. Somewhere in one of our other microservices it's used like that.

Comment: There are other meta characters which [can be present](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940) in a URL like `-?[]()*+`. You don't want to check for those?

Comment: @adiga you're probably right. We're currently porting a legacy RoR project into Typscript and that's how it's been done for years. And would appear those other characters haven't been used yet. lol

Comment: Do you input the full URL or just the domain name? Because domain names only contain `-` in addition to what you have already escaped.

Comment: @adiga full URL without query params.

Comment: I have couple more questions. By, *"without query params"*, your url will always be in the form of `https://domain-name.com` or can it have a path after that: `https://domain-name.com/path`? Do you get the escaped string as input or do you have access to unescaped string? If you have the unescaped string, there is already [a function for escaping all the metacharacters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping).

Comment: @adiga thanks I didn't know this existed, which seems to change the way it works. Currently at the company I work for, we're trying to get to user to manually escape the string being offerred as an input, however I think this could work.

Answer (score 2):

What about, instead of search for every `.` and `/` and check the predecessor character, you write a regexp that find a `.` and `/` that *don't* have `\\` before?

This way, you can avoid the loop and the short circuit to an array

```js
function isValidEscaped(str) {
  const pattern = /[^\\]{2}[./]/g;
  return str.search(pattern) === -1; 
}
```